# Check mime type is correct image?

Tags: php

I want when upload image to check is really image?

I use this-

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$temp = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
$ext = finfo_file($finfo, $temp);
```

Return is something like that-

- text/html
- image/gif
- application/vnd.ms-excel

Maybe if i create array like this-

```
$array = arry("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif");
```

And want to check if `$ext` value is in that array then it's correct image ?

Comment: Sure, you compare against a catalog of accepted mime types.

Comment: yes .you can use with in_array($ext,$array);

Comment: Yes create array of acceptable types and check the coming type exist in that acceptable formats or not with `in_array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below:

```
if(in_array($ext,$array))
{
//image
}
else
{
//not an image
}
```

More information check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thank u, dude : ))

Comment: welcome..you can accept this answer by click the tick mark @Morgan

Comment: Yeah i want, but need to have 15 rep, i have only 11 atm. When i get 15 i will back here and mark it :)

Comment: ok when it allows do it @Morgan